# view data and manipulate date from json using jquery or ajax

Tags: json

First of All i'm a beginner in jquery and ajax, 
what i'm trying to do is view a sample from a whole json file in the link

http://soap.madarat.jo/Services/BusinessApplication1-DomainService1.svc/json/gettasks

and what is the possibility of editing the sample,

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>json test</title>
<script src="js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jtip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function query() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://soap.madarat.jo/Services/BusinessApplication1-       DomainService1.svc/json/gettasks", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        var results = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        var html = '<ol>';
        alert(results.GetTasksResult);
        if (results.GetTasksResult != null) {
            var title;
            alert(results);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.GetTasksResult.RootResults.length; i++ ) {

                entity = results.GetTasksResult.RootResults[i];
                html += '<li>'+entity.DoctorID +' by <b>'+ entity.TaskNote +'</b></li> <br><br> ';
            }
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = html;
        }
    }



  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <button type="button" onclick="query()">jquery</button>
        <div id="results" />


</body>
</html>
```

but nothing happens when i click the button,

why is this happening

thank you

Comment: Why do you use custom Ajax request when you have jQuery to do it for you. And much simpler too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using your requester object correctly. All you did is issue a request but didn't wait for its reply. This code works asynchronously but you thought it's synchronous that's why you started processing data bfore you even got it.

### Use jQuery to make an Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://soap.madarat.jo/Services/BusinessApplication1-DomainService1.svc/json/gettasks",
   success: function(data, status, xhr){
       data = data + "" == data ? $.parseJSON(data) : data;
       var el = $("#results").append("<ol></ol>").children("ol").first();
       if (data.GetTaskResult) {
           $.each(data.GetTaskResult.RootResult, function() {
               el.append("<li>" + this.DoctorID + " by <b>" + this.Tasknote + "</b></li>");
           });
       }
   }
});
```

This may have bugs but it shoudl roughly do the same as your code.

Additionally, you son't need to add json2 library, and I don't know about your jtip.

### Best tip I can give you

Try to first get acquainted with libraries you're using. In your case that would be jQuery. It makes it much simpler for you to write browser independent Ajax code. You haven't used even one bit of it even though it's there. **Learn it, use it**. It shouldn't take you a day to get through all its docs to see how to use it and why it's wise to do so.

**[jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com)**

Comment: Added jQuery documentation link at the end.